# Iterate through NSArrayController in specific order

Tags: objective-c, loops, nsarraycontroller

I need to iterate through an NSArrayController in a coredata model by a specific order.

Lets say that my model has these columns:

```
animal (string)
name (string)
age (int)
```

and I would like to iterate trough the controller like this:

```
for (animal *a in myNsArrayController.arrangedObjects)
{
  // Rest of code
}
```

but I would need to do it ordered by animal age... how can i do that?

A search did not bring me to any usable results..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it builds off of AKV's answer but uses your code and contains the for loop. I think this should work!

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"age" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [myNsArrayController.arrangedObjects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
for (animal *a in sortedArray)
{
  // Rest of code
}
```

Comment: thanks! how can i get the name of the nsarraycontroller i added via itnerface builder? (sorry pretty green here.. )

Comment: No problem, I believe you need to create an IBOutlet for it. So in your .m (or .h) under your interface create an @property here. Name it whatever you would like (say arrayController). Then you should be able to use that instead of myNsArrayController in the above code. That make sense?

Comment: yes! thanks this is clear now.. but... the "for (animal *a in sortedarray) , should animal be replaced with NSArray? i mean, how can i access now the content of the single rows? thank you!

Comment: No probably not. It would probably be whatever your custom object's name is (or model's name). An example would be a Phone class. It could have three attributes like the one you have (let's say zipcode, number, type). I would then do "for (Phone *curPhone in phoneArray) { curPhone.zipcode }" // this would give me that object's zipcode. Otherwise you could try "for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.count; i++) { [[sortedArray objectAtIndex:i] animal] }" // this should hopefully give you the animal as a string

Comment: thanks for your answer, couldnt answer Yesterday because the site was offline! so, if my model is called "Animals" then i would have to write for (Animals *curAnimal in sortedArray) ?? i tried it but it is giving me an error.. "Use of undecleared identifier Animals"..

Comment: Mhmm... is it a Animals a class? Could you simply just import Animals.h at the top of your current class?

Comment: already solved with anotehr question. thanks! i am supposed to use NSManagedObject! thankyou anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

First sort the array based on animal age.

Then loop through it.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"animalAge" ascending:YES];
[yourArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

EDIT:

```
NSArray *yourArray=myNsArrayController.arrangedObjects;
```

Comment: sorry, i am somewhat confused now.. i have an array controller i added trough the interface builder.. where can i get its name? is arraycontroller and array the same?

Comment: create an outlet for that arraycontroller